# Java 8 identity mapping lambda?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I want to find the average area of a few rectangles using aggregate operations in Java 8.

```
Rectangle[] rects = new Rectangle[]{
    new Rectangle(5, 10, 20, 30),
    new Rectangle(10, 20, 30, 40),
    new Rectangle(20, 30, 5, 15)
};

System.out.println("Average area: "
    + Arrays.asList(rects)
    .parallelStream()
    .map((RectangularShape r) -> (r.getWidth() * r.getHeight()))
    .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(o -> o)));
// I don't like this "o -> o"
System.out.println("Expected: 625");
```

However, I find the `o -> o` required by `averagingDouble` kind of silly. Is there a more intuitive replacement for this lambda (maybe even a stock identity lambda somewhere)?

Comment: FYI, `o -> o` is not exactly the identity here -- it is an unboxing function, actually equivalent to `Double::doubleValue`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No need:

```
System.out.println("Average area: "
     + Arrays.asList(rects)
       .parallelStream()
       .mapToDouble((RectangularShape r) -> (r.getWidth() * r.getHeight()))
       .average();
```

(Also, you may find `Stream.of(rects).parallel())` preferable to `Arrays.asList(rects).parallelStream()`.)

Comment: `.getAsDouble()` if you want to get the double value in the Optional (if there is)

Answer (score 3):

There are `identity()` methods in `java.util.function.X` where X = `Function<T,R>`, `UnaryOperator<T>`, `IntUnaryOperator`, `LongUnaryOperator`, `DoubleUnaryOperator`.  The one in `Function<T,R>` uses `T`.  So it looks like `DoubleUnaryOperator::identity` should work, although `o -> o` is a lot less typing.  (Then again, `o -> o` looks more like an emoticon of some kind than an expression.......)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer from @Louis, you might also want to add an `area()` method in `Rectangle` class, and then pass a method reference to `mapToDouble()` method:

```
System.out.println("Average area: "
            + Arrays.asList(rects)
            .parallelStream()
            .mapToDouble(Rectangle::area)
            .average());
```